# How to match one of possible options?

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I use VBA code (using Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library) to replace plain text ID in mails from our bug tracking system to hyperlink.

The message can contain stings like "Bug 1234567" or "Issue 1234567".

I use the following code to match first option:

```vb
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
re.Pattern = "Bug [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

For Each match In re.Execute(body)
    MsgBox match.Value
Next
```

I would like to match both options at once.

The following patterns don't work. Only one option still matched (replaced).

```
re.Pattern = "(Bug|Issue) [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
re.Pattern = "(Bug [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|(Issue [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is fine, but it can be simplified by explicitly stating that it should contain `[0-9]` 7 times, i.e.:

```
(Bug|Issue) [0-9]{7}
```

What you're missing is the `Global` property, which according to [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) specifies that the regular expression should match all occurrences - not just the first. So your entire code becomes:

```
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "(Bug|Issue) [0-9]{7}"

For Each match In re.Execute(body)
    MsgBox match.Value
Next
```

Comment: I'm totally confused. I use   
    'Bug 1234567  
    Issue 1234567'   
as test text. 
Using your (and actually my previous patterns) only 'Issue 1234567' is matched

Comment: Have you set the `Global` property? I just tested this exact code, only replacing `body` with `ActiveDocument.Range.Text` in a Word document with that exact string inserted. It matched both.

Comment: Yes, I did. Here is my code:


    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = "(Bug|Issue) [0-9]{7}"
    
    For Each match In re.Execute(body)
        MsgBox match.Value
    Next

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code. What happens if you 1) replace `body` with `ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Body`, 2) create an empty e-mail, 3) replace its entire contents with `Bug 1234567 Issue 1234567` (copy-and-paste from here), and 4) run that code *only*. Do you only get one message box?

Comment: 2 message boxes, I'm really confused

Comment: The problem is beyond the scope of this question then. There are too many options to go from here to solve in the comments, so you should investigate it further and either make a new question or update this one. See if you can isolate the issue, e.g. try to `Debug.Print` the `body` to see if it contains what you expect.